# Where is DHCP data stored on OpenBSD?

Tags: dhcp, openbsd, isc-dhcpd, dhclient

I'm currently testing with some DHCP and I'm wondering how I can verify if options like "option host-name" or "option domain-name-servers" really worked on the client machine (OBSD 6.6). Where does it store these values?

I've tried looking at hostname.emX but there's obviously no entry.
I also traced the DHCP discover, request etc. on Wireshark where it properly displays the options I want to have on the client machine.

My reference DHCP server is ISC running on Debian.

I appreciate your time!

Comment: Test what you care about, not what you do not. Do you care that it stores it in a file, or do you care about some behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Just as @ctrl-alt-delor says in the comment: See if the client gets configured the way you want. How DHCP does it is irrelevant.

For the record, what it does is to use bog-standard mechanisms to e.g. configure network interfaces, routing, DNS lookup, and whatnot. If the data from the server is stored anywhere central, it's in the DHCP client's memory. It is rather little stuff, if tou think about it.

If you are still curious, go ahead! Read the documentation (*all* man pages, see if there is more detailed/additional documentation available), get the source and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

The leases that [`dhclient(8)`](https://man.openbsd.org/dhclient) gets are stored in `/var/db/dhclient.leases.if`, where `if` is your interface name (e.g. `em0`, `iwm0` etc.)

This is also mentioned in the `dhclient(8)` manual, in the [FILES](https://man.openbsd.org/dhclient#FILES) section.  The format of these files/this file is explained in [`dhclient.leases(5)`](https://man.openbsd.org/dhclient.leases.5).